# How can I turn off push notifications for individual apps in iOS 5?

Tags: iphone, ios, apns

When an app is first installed, occasionally it asks if you would like to receive push notifications for that app. Normally I click 'No' and never think about it again. But yesterday, I accidentally clicked 'Yes', and would now like to turn push off for that app so as to save battery life.

If I go to notifications in the settings app, I can easily change the type of notification to 'None', however is this actually disabling push, or just hiding the notification?

Some of the apps that I am pretty sure I clicked 'No' to push notifications have this setting set to 'Banner' - making me think that these settings aren't related to whether push is turned on or off for that app.

---

What is the correct way to enable/disable push after initially selecting an option on app installation? Are the notifications settings related to push?

Comment: Why would you ever want to do this for ALL notifications?

Comment: @XAleXOwnZX not all, I get mail and one or two others pushed. But really, I don't want a million "tagged in a Facebook photo" or "new content available for this app" notifications like I used to - I get enough mail/messages as it is!

Comment: in which case, entirely disabling push isn't ur goal… which is exactly what one can establish from reading ur question

Comment: @XAleXOwnZX that's not what the question says if you read it, I said "turn push off for that app". The title could probably be clearer, but anyway...

Answer (score 13):

There is no way to disable push notifications. They are handled by Apple's servers and will be sent to your device even if you uninstall the program.

Disabling all the app's respective settings under the Notification Center will only hide them. Refer to [Apple's developer Push documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction/Introduction.html) for more details.

[image]

Specifically, look at the Apple Push Notification (APN) Service, which "transports and routes a notification from a given provider to a given device." Apple says the following about the APN:

> Sometimes APNs might attempt to deliver notifications for an application on a device, but the device may repeatedly refuse delivery because there is no target application. This often happens when the user has uninstalled the application. In these cases, APNs informs the provider through a feedback service that the provider connects with. The feedback service maintains a list of devices per application for which there were recent, repeated failed attempts to deliver notifications. The provider should obtain this list of devices and stop sending notifications to them.

—[Source](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ApplePushService/ApplePushService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH100-SW9)

In short, Push notifications are handled outside of the device. To stop them, once a program has been installed, means the developer of the program must remove your device from the list (or the notification must fail enough for the APN to stop sending them entirely). As a user, there is not way to "stop" them, just hide them from within iOS.

Comment: Thanks. It's not very intuitive IMO though. I guess it makes sense, but personally I think the title 'Push Notifications' rather than 'Alert Style' would make it a lot more intuitive for users.

Comment: @Jordan No it isn't. Apple really should put a "master" slider at the top that reads: Disable push notifications for this app. Marking that should grey out (or better yet remove) all the options above. Would make it a lot clearer and easier to understand.

Comment: Not so sure that this answer is correct now. The same app that I set to 'none' still received a badge notification without me opening it - which means that by clicking 'yes' to the original push notification notification (that's a mouthful..) it doesn't really seem to be possible to actually turn push off for that app, save from setting each individual setting to 'off'. For apps that I originally clicked 'no' to, the badges are still turned on, although push doesn't seem to work for them. Maybe I'm missing something, but this seems like pretty complicated and confusing behavior.

Comment: @Jordan that's normal and doesn't mean push is working, just that badges are enabled. Push notifications are different than mere notifications. Look at Reeder. It has the ability to display badges for unread news feeds but no push functionality. Same with Mail (if you choose to use fetch instead). Apps will still show alerts but they won't be pushed, but displayed when info is fetched.

Comment: the difference was though that the app was never run between no badge being present and a badge popping up. The badge can't have been a local notification as it was related to an online event - hence it must have been push that incremented the badge number. I really can't see any other way the badge would be updated without push, as non Apple apps can't run code in the background. Unless I'm mistaken, it seems that push is still on.

Comment: @Jordan It can still fetch based on an internal interval. What's the app's name? Push, in the simplest of terms, comes from the server. When there's something new, the server sends a notice. Fetching (the traditional alternative) requires your program to poll the server. When push is disabled, it may just use the traditional way instead. I'd like to do more digging.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that apps can only increment badge numbers outside of an app via a push notification or UILocalNotification (the second is something that gets set from within the app so couldn't relate to an online event). I'm also pretty sure that apps are not allowed to use fetch to get data in the background, the API doesn't allow it. There are only 7 allowed background tasks, and I'm sure that fetching mail isn't one of them (It's the Facebook Messenger app btw).

Comment: This answer is wrong. I cannot downvote cos I dont have enough reputation. Push notiifcations will work even if you turn off notification center. Download the Google app and send yourself a mail. You will see a badge even if you have turned off notification center.

Comment: @BobbyAlexander I tested this using Tweetbot. Enabled Push notifications in Tweetbot's native settings. Then disabled (as I wrote in the answer) all settings under iOS. Made a tweet. They replied and I didn't get a peep from iOS. No badge, no sound, nothing. So clearly it works.

Comment: @cksum: It is just hiding the notifications. Push is very much active.

Comment: @BobbyAlexander There's no evidence of that. In fact, when push is enabled in iOS Settings, Tweetbot launches with the mention/reply already loaded (signaled by the blue indicator on the navigation bar at the bottom). When push has been disabled for the app, it does not load the mention/reply. This shows evidence *against* your claim.

Comment: I also don't think this answer is right. For example, if I go to Settings > Mail(...) > Fetch New Data, I can set push notifications to off for the mail app. Some other apps have such a setting too, but most of them don't. Disabling each app on the notification center does just that, they stop showing on the notification center.

Answer (score 6):

You need to turn all 5 setting off for that app in Settings ->Notifications

Turning Notification Center off only removes that app from the Notification Center (swipe down from the top of the screen).  It doesn't turn off alerts, badges, sounds or the lock screen.

Answer (score 2):

Under Settings, go to Notifications
Select Alert Style: NONE

Turn off SOUNDS
Turn off VIEW IN LOCK SCREEN

Answer (score 2):

The original question (asked by Jordan, I believe) has a comment that indicates there may be confusion between Push Notifications and Email Notifications.

He mentioned not wanting to get so many email messages about activity in his apps. All of these answers are just for Push Notifications (which are pop-ups on your device), but even if you manage to turn those off, you'll still get the loads of email notifications.

Some apps, like Pinterest, do not have a place in the mobile app settings to control Email Notifications. You have to login to the app online to access the full settings and turn the Email Notifications off.

Then your inbox will stop filling up!

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall and reinstall and when the prompt appears about notifications, click "No".  Your first choice is absolute.

Comment: This seems to be the only possibility.

Comment: I don't think this works for all apps. I've uninstalled/installed the twitter app, but it didn't prompt me if push should be active/inactive or not.

Comment: The push settings is saved for 24 hours when uninstalling an app. I can't find where I saw this, so you'll have to take my word for it :)

Answer (score 1):

Apple seems to support the theory that disabling the various notification settings will disable push for that app.

"Turn off push notifications: Some applications from the App Store use the Apple Push Notification service to alert you of new data. Applications that extensively rely on push notifications (such as instant messaging applications) may impact battery life. To disable push notifications, go to Settings > Notifications and disable notifications for select applications. Note that this does not prevent new data from being received when the application is opened. Also, the Notifications setting will not be visible if you do not have any applications installed that support push notifications."

http://www.apple.com/batteries/iphone.html

Answer (score 1):

When you disable all notifications for a specific app (alerts,badges, etc) you also disable "push" so data will only be received when you open the app. I verified this with whatsapp.

Answer (score 0):

Settings -> Notifications -> turn on/off (for apps you want to change it)

Comment: I think you're reffering to iOS 4 and earlier. This is about ios 5.

Answer (score 0):

The APNS servers seem to keep a list of enabled push notifications for a device, so at least theoretically, they could filter out everything that is not enabled on a particular device to conserve energy.

I've verified this by observing the traffic patterns on the APNS socket from an iOS 7 device to Apple's push notification servers while modifying the notification settings of an installed app.

The following settings cause traffic to be sent to Apple when toggled:

- Badge app icons
- Sounds
- Banners/Alerts

As long as one of those three is enabled, changes to the remaining two don't cause messages to be sent on the connection, so presumably there is a binary state (interested/not interested) stored on the server, and the details are handled on the device.

Changing the settings for the notification area, switching between banners and alerts, and the settings for the lock screen also seem to be handled locally.

Additionally, when the application is uninstalled, the push servers also seem to be notified.